# What's the most efficient way of tracking employee hours?

Tags: time-management

I'm trying to change the way we do things at our company of 10 people. We can't afford, or better we don't need a full time HR person. Most of our company comprises of developers, and historically every salaried employee was required to log their hours on a daily basis.

There is some work we do that is directly billed to clients, both other tasks that are not. We even track things like time spent on email, meetings, documentation, etc. Trivial tasks that I think shouldn't be tracked as they don't offer much value to us.

It turns out that every employee absolutely hates doing this as it's a time suck in and of itself. Even the owner of the company doesn't like it, and he came up with the policy.

I'm looking to completely change the way everyone thinks about this, but I need help.

Other than tracking time spent on billable client work, I think we can get rid of tracking other trivial tasks. In my mind, it doesn't make sense for salaried employees. It's implied that you're working 40 hour weeks anyways. It gets a little ridiculous, especial for non-developers to enter in hours every day. Imagine a sales, marketing, or support person having to log hours every day. It makes zero sense to me.

The main issue we have is you get paid for 86.67 hours every 2 weeks. If you work less than that, historically we were asked to make it up. If you work more, you bank that time.

I'm just wondering how other small HR free companies handle tracking vacation, sick days, and overtime.

ADDENDUM:

Our development and testing teams usually telecommute, and usually don't work a 9-5 day. Developers often work late at night without access to other teams.

Comment: 86.67 hours every two weeks?  8 hours 40 minutes per day?  Or 86.67 hours semi-monthly?

Comment: We have a non project work bucket for those misc duties like emails, etc, and an internal meeting bucket for meetings not about projects

Comment: @Chad does StackOverflow go into that bucket? :-)

Comment: @enderland - SO is obviously project work :p

Comment: You have historical data - extrapolate from that. You should have an idea of the % each kind of task takes across the workforce, meaning you can bill for that.

Comment: You need to be extremely careful with statements like "The main issue we have is you get paid for 86.67 hours every 2 weeks. If you work less than that, historically we were asked to make it up. If you work more, you bank that time.". If you track salaried employees this way in some cases they can be ruled as hourly employees and you'd be forced to pay any and all 'overtime' they may have worked in the past.

Comment: I, too, am curious about this '86.67' number.

Comment: um salaried employee with fixed hours of work does sound unusual - as stephen says are you not risking problem with exempt/nonexempt.

Why do you need to track time so tightly for professionals especialy for such a tiny company.

Comment: Tell them you need them to sign in / out of the building for fire safety reasons.

Comment: "Imagine a sales, marketing, or support person having to log hours every day." - It is not unusual to see this done. They may spend X hours on a sales call for product x, and Y hours on training for product Y. They can have different organizations paying the bills.

Comment: "Imagine a sales, marketing, or support person having to log hours every day" - My wife is a social worker and has to log her time in 6-minute increments. Every phone call, every meeting, every client visit.

Comment: easiest way is to create custom computers for all staff that can only have one program open at a time. then every time a program opens, it logs to "the cloud" that it was run, at what time, and for how long. And now you know *exactly* what your staff are doing, which, if you implement this, will be complaining about how they can no longer multi-task and job hunting. As you can see, you don't **even need to implement this** to determine what the staff are doing. BAM. Now, about this staff retention problem... i say fire them all, they have no loyalty with all that job hunting.

Comment: @alroc:  that would suck ten times an hour!

Answer (score 7):

The most efficient way is to stop doing it. It's a silly, meaningless concept.

The fact that you require people to work 86.67 hours per pay period is an excellent example of that. Why is the number of hours they are sitting in a chair some how a meaningful metric?

Are clients hiring you to act busy for periods of time, or to accomplish a task? My guess is the latter.

As such, start billing that way. At the very least, stop billing at the micro-level .

I attended a talk by Clement Mok many, many years ago where someone asked him how he billed his firm's time. He said they bill in 4 hour increments, and even then, he'd prefer 8 hour increments.

He stated that "you can't do anything of any worth for a client in less than 4 hours" and I tend to believe that.

Granted, it all depends on your business. If your business is support and clients insist on paying only for time worked, then things get tricky.

But, in general, I think the best solution is to try and get out of the rather silly habit of equating value with time spent on something.

As for tracking vacation and such, again, don't. Trust employees to get stuff they need to get done, and trust them to take vacation when they need it.

Comment: Even if you are billing clients a fixed price for a piece of work, tracking time spent is still important. You're basing your fixed price on an estimate of effort required, and you need to know how accurate your estimates are. If you're underestimating wildly, your fixed price quotes are going to send you broke.

Comment: That's the intent, in theory. In practice, at least in the corporate IT settings I've been in, it's impossible given the seemingly random segmentation of tasks. That is why SWAG is such a common tool now. ;) To quote 'The Wire' it seems as if most enterprise time tracking tasks are really more about 'juking the stats' than providing real meaningful data.

Comment: Many US government contracts want to know how many hours each employee spent on task. They require by law that the time we recorded each day, and there can be no estimated hours. Though the OP is taking it to much more detail than is required.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep that is true. Doesn't change the fact that it's an antiquated idea, though. In fact, a lot of contracts no longer do that. For instance, Bridge construction. The contract states it will be done by a particular date under a particular budget. That seems to make more sense to me.

Comment: Granted, once we start talking 'change management' and the like, I admit that the hourly concept starts to make a bit more sense...though that is really more about billing than it is about employee time tracking.

Comment: Time tracking can be invaluable for future estimates. I'm not even talking billing, costs, etc. I need to be able to have a rough idea what my people can realistically get done in what timespan. If you leave it to just asking "how long will this take" the times vary a lot. Sometimes these estimates are unrealistically short, other times they are unreasonably long. By having past data to reflect on you can see "Bob says this will only take an hour, but the last few times bob did something like this it took three" you go ahead and give bob his three. Rushed work means more mistakes.

Comment: @RualStorge if we're talking physical manufacturing...I could see that. But in terms of creative or IT work, I've never seen any real correlation between past work and future work. There are so many unique variables to each project that estimating a future project on past projects is as arbitrary as making numbers up most of the time. This is another argument for Agile and MVP processes. Estimation just doesn't work that well in those fields.

Comment: @DA sorry we'll have to agree to disagree. Poorly covered metrics or incomplete ones are indeed pretty much worthless. But while there are things with no historical data within a company (brand new project on new tech) there are things that we can safely estimate based on past work. Lets say we're adding a field to a screen. Well we've added fields to the database before, done all the backend stuff to make it available to the UI, and added fields to the UI before. Or at worst something similar. That's a far more reliable estimate than just cornering one dev and going "how long will this take?"

Comment: @RualStorge no need to apologize! :) We've just had different experiences. Granted, the past many years I've worked in large corporations and I have yet to see an IT estimate bear any resemblance to reality. But note that is usually not IT's fault. It's often the craziness that is large corporations and inability to properly manage change requests, vendors, outsourced development, etc.

Comment: @DA I've worked large and mid company IT in situations where estimates were utter crap, as well as ones where estimates were almost so spot on it was creepy. Not that we never had issues, but usually there were things impossible to predict or plan for like we got hit by three hurricanes in just under two months. Metrics collected and interpreted properly are extremely useful, sad fact is most people don't know how to properly collect or utilize them, or simply can't get the necessary buy in at the company to do them properly, which leads to really bad metrics.

Comment: @RualStorge I agree totally with that. In fact, I think that's the main source of my cynicism towards them. Time tracking systems are often overly detailed, or completely lacking in detail. They're also often fudged to meet other demands (making the numbers look good on paper) rather than to act as reflections of reality. That's why I'm a fan of the SWAG model in Agile. It kind of acknowledges the imperfect time tracking systems in a lot of companies.

Answer (score 4):

Really if it takes anyone more than five minutes a day you are doing it wrong. Just what are you doing right now that makes this take so long?

Do you track projects in some kind of Project management system? Most of those have a time tracker feature. Then you only put in time against a project you worked in and leave the rest alone. Then just create a project for other work and let people put it in in one lump sum if you don't need details. So 3 hours against project 1, 2 hours against project b and 3 hours of other. Takes five minutes once you have a good PM system.  You need this by project not only for billing but to able to forecast how well you are doing at estimating vice executing. You need to think about what are your needs as you grow as you design your system. Set up a report to id anyone who is under hours for the pay period. If you don't want a  full blown PM system, use a bug tracker and enter each major project as a bug (we did this one place where I worked)

It is important to make this a required daily input because it becomes a time sink (and a PM nightmare because you have no idea how you are tracking on projected vice expended hours) when people delay doing it and then have to put into a whole month at once to be able to bill the client). I track my time in 15 minute increments and work up to 10 projects in a day (I'm a cross function kind of person who also does some production support) and it still never takes more than 5 minutes to do on a daily basis.

While people might not like time tracking, it is a necessary step especially as you grow eventually you may get people who won't put in the time and because they are working from home, it may take quite sometime to find this out without time tracking. The time sheet is your first clue. It is also proof when something is wrong.

Plus if they are supposed to be working project A and not much was accomplished and you see that they were working on project b or on other stuff, you can then get the priorities refocused fairly quickly with daily time tracking. If you find that someone put 30 hours against other and he worked from home all week and project A that he is assigned to is running late, then it is useful to have the numbers to have a talk with him. Even if all your employees are not slackers now, you have to have systems in place to be able to identify and deal with the slackers who may eventually get hired.  You can't always tell who will be a slacker in advance.

People will whine that it isn't the hours I put in but what I accomplish but that is BS so don't accept that as an excuse to not track time. If you accomplish X,Y,Z and work 20 hours and I pay you for forty (yes even salaried people are supposed to work 40 hours), then you should have accomplished X,Y,Z AND A,B,C and yes you are a slacker who should be fired.

Comment: "While people might not like time tracking, it is a necessary step" = why? Is it, really? Yes PM's live and die by the time sheets, but does that really translate into any sort of efficiency?

Comment: As for your last paragraph, all that philosophy does is teach employees that they should never be more efficient than the arbitrary allotted times given. If working faster only results in more work, then what's the motivation? As such, I have no doubt (yes, I'm exaggerating for effect) that 90% of all time tracking out there (at least in the salaried world) is best guesses, at best, and just totally random at worst.

Comment: @DA, yes it is necessary, there are some people who will not give the work their full attention and you have to be able to protect your company from them. It is silly to expect that every employee is a superstar who is intrinsically motivated. I have personally seen a salaried employee who thought he only needed to work 15-20 hours a week. He got fired and rightly so. Your salary rate is based on an assumption that you will put in 40 hours.

Comment: that entire explanation sounds, to me "we don't trust our employees". IMHO, if that's the concerns, there's bigger problems. The other issue is this assumption of 'putting in 40 hours'. It's this silly assumption that there is always exactly 40 hours of work to be done every week. I've never known that to be true.

Comment: (short of hourly workers, but, of course, they are hourly, not salaried).

Comment: Final thought: Are your time sheets tracking time, or tracking what numbers people put into their time sheets? ;) Sounds like the guy that got fired for only working 20 hours was really fired for being too stupid to fudge his time sheet. ;)

Comment: And if he had put in that he was working on projects and no progress was being made, that too would have been evident. You can only fudge so much.

Comment: Salaried workers are still expected to put in the hours the copmpany planned for them to work when it hired them, why is that such a hard concept for you? If I felt I only needed 20 hours from you, I would have hired you on a part-time basis.

Comment: That's not the concept that's hard to understand. What I find hard to understand is the idea that employees should be judged on the number of hours they work. Yes, it's how we've done it for decades, but we're not building widgets on an assembly line anymore. There's so much research to show that people aren't actually productive 8 hours every day. The insistence that we still all live and die by the time sheet just seems very antiquated.

Comment: +HLGEM Thats not how salarys are suposed to work you are paid to perform a task / role and if you can do the work in 35 hours or 40 it doesn't matter.

The OP's company  is obviously treating salaried employes as hourly paid - Which i believe the authorities can get a bit upset about.

Comment: Yes it is how salaries work. Yes, you can occasionally work less than 40 hours, but they are budgeting the work based on at least 40 hours. If you often work less than that you are cheating your company.

Comment: "If you often work less than that you are cheating your company" only if the company believes the only worth their employees provide is that they sit in a chair for x number of hours. Again, it's an incredibly antiquated way of thinking.

Comment: @DA - so if I can do the same amount of work as my colleagues in one day as they can do in 5 days then I should only have to work 1 day a week according to your theory? Please point me to this "enlightened" employer who isn't so antiquated in their way of thinking.

Comment: FYI - (applies to US only) The text of the Fair Labor Standards Act (FLSA) in regards to salaried employees says "The normal work week for a full-time employee is considered to be a minimum of forty hours, however, greater emphasis is placed on meeting the responsibilities assigned to the position rather than on working a specified number of hours."

Comment: @dunk there aren't many, as corporate thinking, in general, is quite antiquated. That said, there's lots of change happening too. Many places are enacting various methods of 'pay per performance' and a few years ago Best Buy actually did away with the 40 hour work-week and started tracking projects rather than hours. Regardless, whether or not you work a 40 hour week wasn't my point. My point was that in the information age, it's rather ridiculous for companies to think the best metric of productivity is 'hours in seat'.

Comment: @DA - I understand the point you are trying to make and there are many companies who don't necessarily keep track of employees time, but whether spoken or not, it is just generally acknowledged by the overwhelming majority of people that a salaried person is supposed to put in about 40 hours. So even if a timesheet isn't used, people are expected to self manage that time. Alternative means of being paid already exist (ie. salepeople), but that isn't necessarily part of this question which seems specific to salaried employees. Like I said, if I could earn what my coworkers make in 1 day of my..

Comment: effort then I would probably only work 1 or 2 days a week, rather than earn 5 times more and work 5 days. I have so many things I want to do and never enough time to do them.

Comment: @Dunk this would be a great topic for an in depth discussion, though I fear we've already veered off topic. In general, though, I find that corporate management just hasn't evolved past the manufacturing model yet. On a factory floor, hours worked has a direct correlation to widgets made. But in the information age, it's so different. Sadly, we seem to have creeped well beyond the traditional 40 hours per week that we had back in the manufacturing era. (at least in IT, it seems that the norm is closer to 50 hours a week now.)

Answer (score 2):

Things like project corespondents, documentation, project meetings, etc should be built into the cost not the hours. You need to charge a higher per hour rate and just assume certain time and materials above the required hours. In example:

I want to make $100 per man hour on a project, I know that for every 3 actual manhours on a project there is an additional hour involved in project maintenance. So I do not charge for 4 hours because project maintenance is an internal task associated with the project. I charge for 3 and build the maintenance in as a higher fee. $135 Per hour is my service fee.

A bar does not tell you how much they are charging you to wash the cup, or send an email to the dish soap provider to order more, they sell you the drink and eat the rest on the backend.

Answer (score 0):

To keep it simple, I would probably just make a blank Excel spreadsheet for each person to fill out and send back; it would just have Monday-Friday along the top and each of your projects and other tasks along the sides.

Simplify tasks as much as possible - just have one line for "other" to keep track of things like breaks, email, documentation; track vacation/sick days as one line as well. Let everyone know your expectations ("Keep track of things to the nearest hour/half-hour; I won't complain as long as you're tracking 40 hours a week", etc.).

The point to make with everyone is that this is to help out with accounting, and it should take up no more than 5-10 minutes each day. Stress that you're not trying to catch anyone with this (you're not going to call someone in if their "other" category is 2 hours one day), but that you need the data to be as accurate as they can make it.